# Como funcionam os eventos 'request' e 'response' no Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, manipulador-de-evento

Todos sabem como usar o `request` e `response` devidamente como parametros do callback do `http.createServer`, e que usamos esses dois parametros como objetos dentro do callback.

Pesquisei na API DOC's e lá diz que ambos são instâncias do objeto `http.IncomingMensage` e que, este por sua vez, é criado pelo `http.Server`(request) e `http.ClientRequest`(response)...

Fiquei confuso porque na DOC se referem ao `http.Server` como um emissor de eventos e ao `http.ClientRequest` como um construtor de objetos. Tentei entender o código nativo na lib do node e lá achei todos eles em seus lugares mas ainda assim não entendi.

A duvida é: o que acontece por trás de uma construção de server padrão usando o `request` e `response`? O que são exatamente?

Obs, eu sei construir eventListeners e emitters usando o `http.events` de forma simples.

Codigos fonte: [http.ClientRequest](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_client.js), [http.Server](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js), [http.IncomingMensage](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_incoming.js), [http.createServer](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js)

Comment: Que eu saiba são simples objetos que você usa para manipular a requisição e a resposta. Não são eventos. Acho que não entendi bem sua dúvida...

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server, aqui por exemplo se refere ao `request` como um evento que é instância de IncomingMensage @bfavaretto

Comment: Acho que entendi sua confusão, vou responder.

Comment: Conseguiu Resolver essa questão?

Answer (score 4):

Acho que a maneira como [a documentação do Node](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) foi escrita está te confundindo. Ela diz sim que existe um evento chamado `request`, e em seguida mostra o seguinte:

```
function (request, response) { }
```

Essa parte é a assinatura do *listener* desse evento. Ou seja, quando você cria um servidor com [`http.createServer([requestListener])`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener), o `requestListener` que você deve passar é uma função com essa assinatura, uma função que recebe como primeiro argumento um objeto `request` (do tipo `http.IncomingMessage`) e um objeto `response` (do tipo `http.ServerResponse`).

Em outras palavras, o que o `http.createServer([requestListener])` faz é associar um event listener ao evento "request". Toda vez que uma requisição é feita, o servidor emite esse evento, e o listener será invocado com os argumentos indicados.